# Overriding blocks within included Twig templates

Tags: php, twig

Is there a generally "good" way to achieve this functionality? I have read about the 'use' tag, which seems like the best option so far, but I still don't like that it wont let me bring in any outside html, only blocks.

I will use the 'include' tag in the example below to demonstrate the intent I'm trying to describe.

```
#base.html.twig
{% include 'elements/header.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% include 'elements/footer.html.twig' %}

#header.html.twig
<h1>This is my header</h1>
{% block page_title %} Default Page Title {% endblock %}

#index.html.twig
{% extends 'layouts/base.html.twig' %}
{# I want to be able to do this somehow #}
{% block page_title %} This is my overridden page title {% endblock %}
{% block content %} here is the index page content {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Someone filed a ticket here: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1360

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I found a solution. Use the block() function to get the child's block content and pass it to header.html.twig as a variable in the include statement:

```
#base.html.twig
{% include 'elements/header.html.twig' with {page_title: block('page_title')} %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% include 'elements/footer.html.twig' %}

#header.html.twig
<h1>This is my header</h1>
{% if page_title is empty %}
Default Page Title
{% else %}
{{ page_title }}
{% endif %}

#index.html.twig
{% extends 'layouts/base.html.twig' %}
{% block page_title %} This is my overridden page title {% endblock %}
{% block content %} here is the index page content {% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is how I managed to define blocks that need to be rendered in child views. I don't think you'll find a solution that will actually allow you to use blocks inside included views...

Comment: Does this still the best solution? To have a `block` within an `include` seems so trivial to me.

Comment: That's just brilliant!

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem and you made my day !

Comment: I shall name you Sir Bruce Webberig Lee

Comment: You sir, just made my day! :-)

Comment: Does not work for me if the `block` contains HTML For example if you want to include header, body and footer, and in the body have the block body substituted... You then have to do `{{ body|raw }}` instead of `{{ body }}` so the HTML is not escaped.

Comment: if index.html.twig does not have a page_title block it will not work. You will need to add an empty page_title block inside your base.html.twig content block to be sure all works as intended.

Comment: @HerrNentu' : good point! see the needed changes in my answer

Answer (score 20):

I found a **good and real** solution reading the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html) for the ***embed*** tag. I'm using Twig 2.0 in Symfony 4.

## My structure

```
#templates/base.html.twig
{% block navbar %}
    <nav>
    {% block menu %}
        {% include '_menu' %}
    {% endblock menu %}
    </nav>
{% endblock navbar %}
{% block content %}
    {# several blocks defined #}
    {% block footer '' %}
{% endblock content %}

#templates/_menu.html.twig
<ul>
    {% block sub_app_menu_itens %}
        <li>Main App Menu Item</li>
    {% endblock sub_app_menu_itens %}
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Another menu item</li>
    <li>Yet another menu item</li>
</ul>
```

With code above, when I create my ***index.html.twig*** the only code needed to show de default things is

```
#templates/index.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

and override blocks defined.
But, when I need to create another page, that use these skeleton, if I try to override *block sub_app_menu_itens* in another _partial template included, doesn't work. `<li>Main App Menu Item</li>` is always showed and never overwritten (code above)

```
#templates/subapp/index.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{{ 'agencia.homepage'|trans }}{% endblock %}
{% block menu %}
    {% include 'subapp/_menu.html.twig' %}
{% endblock menu %}
{% block user_content %}Content Here{% endblock %}

#templates/subapp/_menu.html.twig
{% extends '_menu.html.twig' %}
{% block sub_app_menu_itens %}
        <li>SubApp Menu Item</li> 
{% endblock sub_app_menu_itens %}
```

`<li>SubApp Menu Item</li>` is never showed. Tried a lot of things like `extends` and even conditionals with no luck.

## THE Solution

The ***embed*** tag solve the child partial templates blocks to be overwritten.

```
#templates/subapp/index.html.twig
{% block menu %}
    {% embed '_menu.html.twig' %}
        {% block sub_app_menu_itens %}
            {% include 'subapp/_menu.html.twig' %}
        {% endblock sub_app_menu_itens %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock menu %}
```

And simplifing _partial template to have only the html needed

```
#templates/subapp/_menu.html.twig 
    <li>SubApp Menu Item</li>
```

Now `<li>SubApp Menu Item</li>` will be displayed on the right place of _menu template.

Thinking in levels, a `include` works like a sublevel (parsed) and all things are only override on the same level, so `include` doesn't allow to override in another include. Instead, `embed` templates are bring to the same level (not parsed) and so you can override things.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done. Here's my solution to the problem by passing a variable to the view.

```
#layout.twig
{% if sidebar is empty %}
    This is the default sidebar text.
{% else %}
    {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

#index.twig
{% extends "layout.twig" %}
{% block sidebar %}
    This is the sidebar. It will override the default text.
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    This is the content.
{% endblock %}

#index.php (SlimPHP)
$app->render('index.twig', ['sidebar' => true]);
```

Since I'm using SlimPHP the way I call it is by passing `sidebar` variable to the the view. This can be extended further by using different variables passed to the view, so you can selected `sidebar1`, `sidebar2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a very simple hack:

Basically it behaves this way because without a `{% extends "foo.html.twig" %}` it doesn't understand the blocks and simply renders them in place.

So let's extend... nothing:

```
{% extends "nothing.html.twig" %}
```

This nothing is really just 1 block:

```
# nothing.html.twig
{% block main %}
{% endblock %}
```

The only thing is that you need to wrap everything in a block, this fake "main" block.

Answer (score 0):

Improvement on @webberig's solution, that fixes blocks that are not overridden in all extending templates (comment by @HerrNentu'):

```
#base.html.twig
{% if block("page_title") is defined %}
     {% include 'elements/header.html.twig' with {page_title: block('page_title')} %}
{% else %}
     {% include 'elements/header.html.twig' with {page_title: null} %}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% include 'elements/footer.html.twig' %}

#header.html.twig
<h1>This is my header</h1>
{% if page_title is empty %}
Default Page Title
{% else %}
{{ page_title }}
{% endif %}

#index.html.twig
{% extends 'layouts/base.html.twig' %}
{% block page_title %} This is my overridden page title {% endblock %}
{% block content %} here is the index page content {% endblock %}
```