# Twig block indirect extending and appending

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have splitted my layout and templates to few partials, mostly because of old `Symfony1` habits.

file `layout.html.twig`:

```
...
<body>
  {{ include("ABCBundle:Partials:breadcrumbs.html.twig") }}
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
...
```

file `breadcrumbs.html.twig`

```
<div class="abc">
  {% block breadcrumbs %}
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

file `show.html.twig`

```
{% extends "ABCBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
  {{ parent() }}
  abc
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  (something something)
{% endblock %}
```

Funny thing is, when I render `show.html.twig`, I can put data into `body` block, and everything works fine, but I can't do anything with `breadcrumbs` block. Whatever I do - write something inside that block or call `parent()`, nothing happens, only content from `breadcrumbs.html.twig` is being rendered. There's also no error about calling `parent()` and any other error related to extending block.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `{% include "..." %}` rather than `{{ include("...") }}`

According to the twig documentation, the `{% include %}` [tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) "includes a template and returns the rendered content of that file into the current namespace" where as the include [function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) "returns the rendered content of a template"

(Meaning the include function just returns the rendered content, where the tag adds the content to the current namespace which would include the blocks you defined)

Comment: thanks for helpful info! I'm sure this will become very helpful in future tasks, but unfortunately didn't solve my problem.

Comment: If you remove the call to parent(), does it show anything you put in the block in show.html.twig?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It looks like it doesn't matter what I write inside `breadcrumbs` block of `show.html.twig` - default content from `breadcrumbs.html.twig` is always displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

It looks like you can't extend block included in layout's `include`, from template extending this layout:

```
[partial.html.twig]  --- [      layout.html.twig       ] --- [   template.html.twig  ]
 {% block abc %}        {% include 'partial.html.twig' %}   {% extends layout.html.twig %}
                                                            {% block abc%} aaa {%endblock %}
```

You have to perform a little hack, including adding extra content to layout and replacing original block from `partial.html.twig` with conditional. More here: [Overriding blocks within included Twig templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160977/1407357)