# Tag 'use' of twig templating system duplicate content

Tags: html, symfony, inheritance, twig, template-engine

Using the sf2.6.4 and the Twig templating system, I have a weird behaviour with the tag 'use'.

**With a simple base template defining a default navbar and header content :**

```
{# base.html.twig #}
<html lang="fr">
  <head></head>
  <body>

    {%  block navbar %}<hr> nav bar foo bar<hr>{% endblock %}

    <!-- a default header -->
    {% block header %}
        {%  include 'AppBundle:TestingTwigUse:header.html.twig' %}
    {% endblock %}

  </body>
```

**With the given default header.html.twig template :**

```
{#  header.html.twig  #}
{% block header_container %}
  {% block header_title %}&lt;h1>Default title</h1>{% endblock %}
  {% block header_content %}
    <div>
        This default text header, blablabla...
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**When I try to build an index template,  inheriting the base one and overiding the header content using 'use' tag like following :**

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends "AppBundle:TestingTwigUse:base.html.twig" %}

{% block header %}
    {% use 'AppBundle:TestingTwigUse:header.html.twig' %}
    {% block header_container %}
        {{ parent() }}
        {% block header_content %}
            ***** child template specific content ****
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have the strange following result with header_content block twice :

```
    ***** child template specific content **** ***** child template specific content ****
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly two solutions :

With **'use'**, we can get the part we want to keep but loosing inheritance :

```
{% block header %}
    {% use 'AppBundle:TestingTwigUse:header.html.twig' with header_title as parent_header_title %}
    {% block header_title %}
        {{ block('parent_header_title') }}
    {% endblock %}
    ***** child template specific content ****
{% endblock %}
```

**The one is 'embeb' that combines include AND extends behaviour :**

```
{% block header %}
    {% embed 'AppBundle:TestingTwigUse:header.html.twig'  %}
       {%  block header_content %}
       ***** child template specific content ****
       {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thinkg the problem is you have two `header_content` blocks - one in the `index.twig.html`, second in the `parent()` call. Second definition overrides first which leads to duplications after compilation.

If you want to override the default text - you should remove `parent()` call. If you want to update (append) the default text - you should refactor your blocks structure to avoid identical names.

**UPD** Try following index

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends "AppBundle:TestingTwigUse:base.html.twig" %}

{% block header_content %}
     ***** child template specific content ****
{% endblock %}
```

**UPD 2** Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160977/1361089)

> I found a solution. Use the block() function to get the child's block
>   content and pass it to header.html.twig as a variable in the include
>   statement

Comment: Thanks but removing `parent()` call is removing  the "Default Tiltle" that I want precisly keep. *My aim is to override `header_content` only.* The output of my first post is incomplete but containing the "navbar" and the "Default Title" from header.html.twig before the duplication.

Comment: I've tried it before, and nothing happens. We just retreive the original header.hthm.twig file. That's sound normal for me, if this kind of code worked, we have to consider that multiple inheritance should work with Twig and this is not the case regarding to the doc :     [Template inheritance is one of the most powerful Twig's feature but it is limited to single inheritance..](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html)

Comment: we cannot just retrieve, last block statement should override block content instead of placing it alongside.

Comment: @Olivier check referenced solution

Comment: This is interesting but a little verbose and defining the part we want to override in the parent template is not convient.